# how to show select option value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

hello I create database 2 table  1 vn_rent 2 amount_cus

from insert to vn_rent

i user code this select option value

```
<?php
session_start();
//PUT THIS HEADER ON TOP OF EACH UNIQUE PAGE
if(!isset($_SESSION['id_user'])){
  header("location:index.php");
  header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
}


include_once('config/dbconnect.php');

$id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
$rn_first_name = $_POST['rn_first_name'];
$rn_last_name = $_POST['rn_last_name'];
$rn_gostart = $_POST['rn_gostart'];
$rn_endstart = $_POST['rn_endstart'];
$time_gostart = $_POST['time_gostart'];
$time_endstart = $_POST['time_endstart'];
$rn_tel = $_POST['rn_tel'];
$rn_amount = $_POST['rn_amount'];
$rn_svan = $_POST['rn_svan'];
$rn_destination = $_POST['rn_destination'];
$id_invoice = $_POST['id_invoice'];
$Status = $_POST['Status'];
$vn_dtial = $_POST['vn_dtial'];
$rn_place = $_POST['rn_place'];
$id_vn_order = $_POST['id_vn_order'];
$travel_id = $_POST['travel_id'];
$province_id = $_POST['province_id'];
$am_id = $_POST['am_id'];

$date = "$rn_gostart"; //กำหนดค้นวันที่

$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from vn_rent where rn_gostart = '$date'");
$ckd = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($ckd >= 3){

$msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; วันที่จองเต็มแล้ว
</div>";
}else{


$sql = "INSERT INTO vn_rent (id_user,rn_first_name,rn_last_name,rn_gostart,rn_endstart,time_gostart,time_endstart,rn_tel,rn_amount,rn_svan,Status,vn_dtial,rn_place,rn_destination,travel_id,province_id,am_id)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$rn_first_name',' $rn_last_name ','$rn_gostart','$rn_endstart','$time_gostart','$time_endstart','$rn_tel','$rn_amount','$rn_svan','$Status','$vn_dtial','$rn_place','$rn_destination','$travel_id','$province_id','$am_id')";


//คำสั่ง insert  2 ตาราง
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
     $id_van = $con->insert_id;
   $con->query("INSERT INTO invoice 
                   (id_user, id_vn_order,id_van) 
              VALUE($id_user, $id_vn_order, $id_van)");

    $id_invoice = $con->insert_id;
    $con->query("UPDATE vn_rent  
                    SET id_invoice = '$id_invoice' 
                 WHERE id_van = $id_van");


    $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; s] จองรถตู้สำเร็จ โปรดรอการตอบรับทาง Email !
     </div>";
} 



else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
}


$con->close();


/*

 $sql = "INSERT INTO vn_rent (id_user,rn_first_name,rn_last_name,rn_dstart,rn_estart,rn_tel,rn_amount,rn_svan,Status,vn_dtial,rn_place,rn_destination)
VALUES ('$id_user', '$rn_first_name',' $rn_last_name ','$rn_dstart','$rn_estart','$rn_tel','$rn_amount','$rn_svan','$Status','$vn_dtial','$rn_place','$rn_destination')";


$sql1="INSERT INTO invoice (id_invoice,id_van,id_user,id_vn_order)
VALUES ('$id_invoice', '$id_van',' $id_user ','$id_vn_order')";


  if($con->multi_query($sql))
 {
   $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; s] จองรถตู้สำเร็จ โปรดรอการตอบรับทาง Email !
     </div>";
  }
  else
  {
   $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; error while registering !
     </div>";
  }





 $con->close();*/


?>
```

Simple Select table amount_cus insert to vn_rent

```
<?php
include "config.php";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM amount_cus"; 
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query); ?> 

  <select class="select-search" name="am_id"> 
  <?php while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $line['am_id'];?>"> 
        <?php echo $line['am_text'];?>
     </option>  
  <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

[[image: [IMaGE from vn_rent]]]

[[image: [amount_cus]]]

OK I'm sorry i'm not good english

What I will do is. I will make changes, but the problem is, I do it to extract data from tables and lists amount_cus selected first. And along with other data

Comment: What you have need exact ?

Answer (score 0):

i user code $row

```
<select class="select-search" name="am_id"> 
<option value="<?php echo $row['am_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row['am_id'];?> </option>
```

[image: [[VIEW IMAGE]]]

but show incomplete I want to show it , not choice.

For example, I selected five data will show.

```
5
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```